# android onItemSelected triggers itself when activity starts

Tags: android, android-spinner

I don't know why the `onItemSelected` triggerd it self when the activity starts ? is that because i have initials data on the spinner from the start ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `onItemSelected()` method will be called whenever the `Spinner` changes its selection. This *includes* when it initially gets its default selection.

If you need to skip doing work that first time, use a `boolean` flag to track whether or not this is the first `onItemSelected()` call.

Comment: i thought that , you 256K :) i am not even 200 :)

Comment: when activity starts i will make that boolean faluse but how to change it ? because it will alswasy stay false ,

Comment: @FernadoMargin: Have a data member of your activity named `isFirstOnItemSelected`. Set it to be `true` in the initializer. In `onItemSelected()`, if `isFirstOnItemSelected` is `true`, set it to `false`, otherwise do your regular work.